# Globally installed npm package not found when installed with NVM using oh-my-zsh

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, nvm, oh-my-zsh

Using oh-my-zsh (on Mac), I have NVM installed and am running the latest LTS version of Node.

I have globally installed the two versions of this package: https://github.com/IBM/openapi-to-graphql

`which openapi-to-graphql` returns `/Users/myUser/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin/openapi-to-graphql` which is what I'd expect.

However,

`which openapi-to-graphql-cli` returns `openapi-to-graphql-cli not found`
even though I can see it if I `run npm list --g --depth 0`

```
/Users/myUser/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib
├── corepack@0.10.0
├── lerna@4.0.0
├── npm@8.1.0
├── openapi-to-graphql-cli@2.5.2
├── openapi-to-graphql@2.5.2
└── read-package-json@4.1.1
```

If I run the `which` command against the other packages, most of them return as expected apart from `read-package-json` which also returns an error.

I've tried uninstalling / reinstalling the `openapi-to-graphql-cli` package globally but no luck.

The command I need to run in the terminal is `openapi-to-graphql-cli <inputFile> --save <outputFile>`

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was two fold. Firstly there is a bug in the package at the time of posting that prevents the CLI from working: https://github.com/IBM/openapi-to-graphql/issues/418

I rolled back to version `2.5.0` which fixed this issue.

The second problem was because of the bug I made the assumption I was running the commands wrong in the terminal so I started running `openapi-to-graphql-cli <command>` which is incorrect. Commands should start with `openapi-to-graphql` as per [the docs](https://github.com/IBM/openapi-to-graphql/tree/master/packages/openapi-to-graphql-cli).